# Emit an event to a child object

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I'm writing a nodejs module and trying bind an event emitter to "scrappy.get".  It seems that I can only bind it to "scrappy"   .... so "scrappy.get(key).on('complete'...."  does not work.

How do I send the event to the child object 'get'?

My NodeJS module:

```
     var util = require('util'),
    EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function Scrappy(id) {
}

util.inherits(Scrappy, EventEmitter);

Scrappy.prototype.get = function (key) {
  var self = this;
  self.emit('complete', "here");
  **return this;**
}

module.exports = Scrappy;
```

My NodeJS app code:

```
var Scrappy = require('./scrappy.js')
var scrappy = new Scrappy("1234");

scrappy.get("name").on('complete', function(data){
    console.log("secondary");
});
```

Result:

```
scrappy.get("name").on('complete', function(data){
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
```

Edit: Solved.  Adding "return this;"  solved it for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `this` is different because you're in a different function. You need to instead capture the Scrappy instance's `this` to a variable and access that instead:

```
Scrappy.prototype.get = function (key) {
  var self = this;
  redisclient.get(key, function(err, reply) {
    self.emit('complete', reply);
  });
};
```

Also, instead of manually mutating the prototype with `__proto__` and such, typically what node core uses (and what many module developers use) is the built-in `util.inherits()`. The other things is that you're not returning the instance from `get()`. Here's an example with these changes:

```
var util = require('util'),
    EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function Scrappy(id) {
}
util.inherits(Scrappy, EventEmitter);

Scrappy.prototype.sendToEngine = function(message) {

};
Scrappy.prototype.set = function(key, value) {

};
Scrappy.prototype.get = function(key) {
  var self = this;

  redisclient.get(key, function(err, reply) {
    self.emit('complete', reply);
  });

  return this;
};

module.exports = Scrappy;
```

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to be working.  In the nodejs app, I'm still getting:

scrappy.get("name").on('complete', function(data){
                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Comment: The main problem is that you're not returning the Scrappy instance from `get()` to be able to call `.on()`.

Comment: mscdex, thank you for your assistance, but it isn't working for me.

Comment: I've updated my question to simplify the code as much as I can - still getting the same problem.